# Script Processes in Parallel

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, grep, parallelism

I would like to parse apache access log w.r.t IPs. I have used the following code, but it took nearly 90sec.

```
grep "^$CLIENT_IP" /var/log/http/access.log > /tmp/access-$CLIENT_IP.log
```

Then i tried alternative as below.

```
sed -i -e "/^$CLIENT_IP/w /tmp/access-$CLIENT_IP.log" -e '//d' /var/log/http/access.log
```

even this took 60+ seconds as well.

There are 1200 IPs to parse. I would like to know is there any way we can implement parallelism to reduce the runtime.

Comment: Why did you use `-i` with `sed`? Did that not modify the original log file?

Comment: Is it a requirement to save the parsed log to separate files?

Comment: -i is used to moving the lines from one file to another. Yes, that's the requirement.

Comment: No, `-i` is for doing in-place editing of the input file.

Comment: I'm deleting those copied lines from the input file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're doing this in a shell loop over all IP addresses, possibly with the IP addresses coming from a text file.  Yes, that would be slow, with one invocation of `sed` or `grep` per IP address.

Instead, you may get away with a single use of `sed`, if you prepare carefully.

First, we have to create a `sed` script, and we do that from a file `ip.list` which contains the IP addresses, one address per line:

```
sed -e 'h' \
    -e 's/\./\\./g' \
    -e 's#.*#/^&[[:blank:]]/w /tmp/access-#' \
    -e 'G' \
    -e 's/\n//' \
    -e 's/$/.log/' ip.list >ip.sed
```

This `sed` stuff does, for each IP address,

1. Copy the address to the "hold space" (an extra buffer in `sed`).
2. Change `.` in the "pattern space" (the input line) into `\.` (to match the dots properly, your code did not do this).
3. Prepend `^` and append `[[:blank:]]/w /tmp/access-` to the pattern space.
4. Append the unmodified input line from the hold space to the pattern space with a newline in-between.
5. Delete that newline.
6. Append `.log` to the end of the line (and implicitly output the result).

For a file that contains

```
127.0.0.1
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.100
```

this would create the `sed` script

```
/^127\.0\.0\.1[[:blank:]]/w /tmp/access-127.0.0.1.log
/^10\.0\.0\.1[[:blank:]]/w /tmp/access-10.0.0.1.log
/^10\.0\.0\.100[[:blank:]]/w /tmp/access-10.0.0.100.log
```

Note that you will have to match a blank character (space or tab) after the IP address, otherwise the log entries for `10.0.0.100` would go into the `/tmp/access-10.0.0.1.log` file. Your code omitted this.

This can then be used on your log file (no looping):

```
sed -n -f ip.sed /var/log/http/access.log
```

I haven't ever tested writing to 1200 files from one and the same `sed` script.  If it doesn't work, then try the below `awk` variation instead.

---

A similar solution with `awk` involves reading the IP addresses into an array first and then matching them against each row.  This requires one single `awk` invocation:

```
awk 'FNR == NR  { list[$1] = 1; next }
     $1 in list { name = $1 ".log"; print >>name; close name }' ip.list /var/log/http/access.log
```

Here, we give `awk` both the IP list and the log file at the same time.  When `NR == FNR` we know we're still reading the first file (the list), and we add the IP numbers into the associative array `list` as keys, and continue with the next line of input.

If the `FNR == NR` condition is not true, we're reading from the second file (the log file) and we test whether the very first field of the input line is a key in `list` (this is a plain string comparison, not a regular expression match).  If it is, we append the line to the appropriately named file.

We have to be careful with closing the output file, as we might otherwise run out of opened file descriptors. So there's going to be a lot of opening and closing files for appending, but it's still going to be faster than calling `awk` (or any utility) once per IP address.

---

I'd be interested in knowing if these things work for you and what the approximate running time might be.  I have tested the solutions only on extremely small sets of data.

---

Of course, we could go with your idea of just brute forcing it through throwing multiple instances of e.g. `grep` on the system in parallel:

Ignoring the fact that we don't match the dots in the IP addresses correctly, we might to something like

```
xargs -P 4 -n 100 sh -c '
    for n do
        grep "^$n[[:blank:]]" /var/log/http/access.log >"/tmp/access-$n.log"
    done' sh <ip.list
```

Here, `xargs` will give at most 100 IP addresses at a time from the `ip.list` file to a short shell script. It will arrange with four parallel invocations of the script.

The short shell script:

```
for n do
    grep "^$n[[:blank:]]" /var/log/http/access.log >"/tmp/access-$n.log"
done
```

This will just iterate over the 100 IP addresses that `xargs` gives it on its command line, and apply pretty much the same `grep` command that you had, the difference is that there will be four of these loops running in parallel.

Increase `-P 4` to `-P 16` or something related to the number of CPUs that you have.  The speedup probably would not be linear as each parallel instance of `grep` would read from and write to the same disk.

Except for the `-P` flag to `xargs`, all things in this answer should be able to run on any POSIX system.  The `-P` flag for `xargs` is non-standard but implemented in GNU `xargs` and on BSD systems.

Answer (score 1):

For various approaches:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066609/fastest-possible-grep

In addition to that, 
If you're doing this a lot then an SSD is probably the way to go.  Touching the HD is the killer for something like this.

You have large numbers of different greps to run.  Make a script which launches script commands (say, one per core) into the background and then tracks when they're done, as they're complete launch more.

When I was doing it I could get all 12 cores running at 100% CPU usage but you may find your resource limit to be something else.  Given all your jobs want the same file if you're not on an SSD you might want to copy that file around so they're not sharing.

Answer (score 0):

If `/var/log/http/access.log` is bigger than RAM and thus cannot be cached, then running more processes in parallel can be a good alternative to reading `access.log` multiple times - especially if you have multiple cores. This will run one `grep` per IP in parallel (+ a couple of helping wrapping processes).

```
pargrep() {
    # Send standard input to grep with different match strings in parallel
    # This command would be enough if you only have 250 match strings
    parallel --pipe --tee grep ^{} '>' /tmp/access-{}.log ::: "$@"
}
export -f pargrep
# Standard input is tee'ed to several pargreps.
# Each pargrep gets 250 match strings and thus starts 250 processes.
# For 1200 ips this starts 3600 processes taking around 1 GB RAM,
# but it reads access.log only once
cat /var/log/http/access.log |
  parallel --pipe --tee -N250 pargrep {} :::: ips
```